# The return type 'Future<dynamic>' isn't a 'Future<bool>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

after update my sdk version the error is showing

> The return type 'Future' isn't a 'Future', as required by the closure's context

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text(
                    "Start Quiz",
                  ),
                  content: Text("ohh snap"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Ok',
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ));
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onWillPop` provide a future on callback  `Future<bool> Function();`

Try like

```dart
return WillPopScope(
  child: Text("a"),
  onWillPop: () async {
    return await showDialog(
```

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  return WillPopScope(
    child: Text("a"),
    onWillPop: () async {
      return await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                  "Start Quiz",
                ),
                content: Text("ohh snap"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Ok',
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
    },
  );
}
```